# Как добавить к узлу дерева дерева квадратики по числу его дочерних узлов?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Очень сложно описать задачу, так что вопрос абстрактный, реализацию в ответе я применю по другому назначению.

Предположим есть `TreeView`, который заполняется из набора (в моем случае XML). Как изменить шаблон `TreeViewItem` так, чтобы возле заголовка (например справа) отрисовалось несколько элементов управления по числу дочерних элементов? Пусть контейнером для квадратиков будет `StackPanel`. Очень желательно это осуществить в XAML с конвертером.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял суть, поэтому несколько вслепую. В целом решение довольно прямолинейное: добавить в `HierarchicalDataTemplate` элемента дерева `ItemsControl`, который прибиндить к подэлементам. У `ItemsControl` задать панелью `StackPanel`.

Итак, положим, что у нас есть класс элемента и некоторое дерево.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public Item (string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public Item Root { get; }

        public MainWindow ()
        {
            Root = new Item("Root") {
                Items = {
                    new Item("Item 1") {
                        Items = {
                            new Item("Item 1.1") {
                                Items = {
                                    new Item("Item 1.1.1"),
                                    new Item("Item 1.1.2"),
                                    new Item("Item 1.1.3"),
                                }
                            },
                            new Item("Item 1.2"),
                            new Item("Item 1.3"),
                        }
                    },
                    new Item("Item 2") {
                        Items = {
                            new Item("Item 2.1"),
                            new Item("Item 2.2"),
                            new Item("Item 2.3"),
                            new Item("Item 2.3"),
                        }
                    },
                    new Item("Item 3"),
                    new Item("Item 4"),
                }
            };
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше описываем нужные шаблоны в XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Control.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="tplItemRect" DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <Rectangle Width="6" Height="6" Stroke="DeepSkyBlue"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="tplHorizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tplItemRect}"
                        ItemsPanel="{StaticResource tplHorizontal}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Control.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Items, ElementName=root}"/>

</Window>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image]

Comment: Да, похоже, это то, что нужно. Попробую применить это к боевой задаче. Возможно будут вопросы, но вроде все понятно :)

Comment: На вопрос вы ответили, но появился новый, как продолжение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451202/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B