# Как у узла дерева продублировать дочерние элементы?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Изначально вопрос звучал иначе и я получил на него ответ. Вот ссылка

[Как добавить к узлу дерева дерева квадратики по числу его дочерних узлов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451025/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Но это не позволило в полной мере осуществить мою задумку. Поэтому я усложняю вопрос.

Как сделать так, чтобы эти квадратики можно было выделять? То есть чтобы они были полноценными TreeViewItem, а не просто квадратиками? При этом они не должны иметь потомков, как реальные дочерние узлы. Вот схематический пример того, что я хочу получить:

```
узел1
    узел11(без продолжения)
    Узел12(без продолжения)
    узел11(реальный)
        узел111(без продолжения)
        узел111(реальный)
    узел12(реальный)
        узел121(без продолжения)
        узел121(реальный)
```

То есть в таком виде как выше, должно отобразиться вот такое дерево

```
узел1
    узел11
        узел111
    узел12
        узел121
```

Если формулировка не понятна, объясните в чем, попытаюсь перефразировать.

Comment: Может вам все-таки достаточно квадратики на чекбоксы заменить?

Comment: @ad1Dima, нет, не достаточно. Дополнительные узлы должны быть как бы уменьшенным вариантом реальных. При выделении реальных узлов я должен получать всю информацию, что в них содержится. По выделению дополнительных узлов - лишь часть ее. В бою само дерево представляет из себя граф, а дополнительные узлы - это стрелки, соединяющие родительский узел с дочерними. Стрелки, как и реальные узлы, должны выделяться, а для этого должны быть полноценными TreeViewItem. Но разметку со стрелками я сооружу уже сам, мне нужен лишь намек как это все грамотно связать. поэтому вернемся к нашим квадратикам.... :)

Comment: Вы хотите визуализировать Дерево с весами на ребрах?

Comment: @ad1Dima, с чем и на чем? Я не понял. Вот что я хочу визуализировать http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/images/weblogs_sqlteam_com/joew/WindowsLiveWriter/DoesordermatterinaJOINclause_74C5/JoinPerform1-2008-02-29_2.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Ничего не понял. Опять вслепую. Если нужна возможность выделять элементы, то нужно заменить `ItemsControl` на `ListBox`. Придётся добавить триггер для скрытия списка в случае нуля элементов, потому что `ListBox`, а отличие от `ItemsControl`, по умолчанию рисует границу, и пустой список будет выглядеть не очень красиво.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Control.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="tplItemRect" DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <Rectangle Width="6" Height="6" Stroke="DeepSkyBlue"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="tplHorizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tplItemRect}"
                        ItemsPanel="{StaticResource tplHorizontal}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter TargetName="lstItems" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Control.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Items, ElementName=root}"/>

</Window>
```

Выглядеть будет так:

[image]

Если вам нужно выделять элементы (либо один, либо несколько), можно сделать чекбоксы или радиобатоны:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Control.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="tplItemCheck" DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <CheckBox/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="tplHorizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tplItemCheck}"
                        ItemsPanel="{StaticResource tplHorizontal}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Control.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Items, ElementName=root}"/>

</Window>
```

Выглядеть будет так:

[image]

Хотя почему не поместить чекбоксы прямо в элементы — я не понял.

Comment: Так я смогу выделить элемент в дереве и элемент в каждом листбоксе. А должен выделяться лишь один элемент. Каждый квадратик по возможности должен быть представлен как `TreeViewItem`. Это даст возможность выделить либо узел либо квадратик, к тому же это даст возможность использовать `TreeView.SelectedItem` для дальнейшей привязки данных. В комментарии к вопросу я дал ссылку на картинку того, что я хочу получить из дерева. То есть в данном случае квадратики - будущие стрелки.

Comment: @iRumba Не вижу на картинке двойных иерархий, там простое дерево, и то специфически нарисованное. / Предлагаемый вами гуй потребует свой собственный IsSelected (с ручной обработкой выделения и прочего), потому что дерево не предполагает наличия одного элемента в двух параллельных списках. У меня ощущение, что вы сильно мудрите и хотите чего-то странного. Опишите по-человечески (можно кодом, можно картинкой) вашу модель данных и нарисуйте гуй (хоть в пейнте, хоть как).

Comment: на картинке именно то, что я хочу получить. Там простое дерево, только стрелочки можно выделять, как и итемы. Дерево строится по XML документу, однако стрелки не являются его реальными частями, они черпают наполнение из элементов, которые они соединяют с родительским. Я не хочу делать выделение вручную и все прочее, для этого стрелочки должны быть дубликатами дочерних элементов, но не будут порождать потомков.

Comment: Для того, чтобы понять полностью, что я хочу, нужно открыть SQL Server Management Studio и выполнить какой нибудь (желательно сложный) запрос с опцией построения плана запроса. Посмотреть на этот план, повзаимодействовать с элементами интерфейса. Я делаю собственный PlanViewer, только предусматриваю в нем то, что мне кажется неудобным в родном просмотрщике.